# Ipython notebook matplotlib gui backends dlopen import error on osx

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

On OSX 10.11.6 using Anaconda python 2.7 when switching to (any) gui matplotlib backend from `%matplotlib inline` in jupyter ipython notebook generates:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/.../anaconda2/lib/libQtGui.4.8.7.dylib   Reason:
>   Incompatible library version: libQtGui.4.dylib requires version 39.0.0
>   or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 34.0.0

Any suggestions which one of the mentioned libraries I am supposed to install/update or both? And how to find these for OSX?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem since I updated a bunch of my conda packages yesterday.  I tried `conda uninstall matplotlib` followed by `conda install matplotlib` and it did not go away.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved after I did this:

```
conda update libpng
```

Which resulted in:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

    libpng: 1.6.17-0 --> 1.6.22-0
```